# The Websocket events listener in nestjs gateway not working in production

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, react-native, nestjs

The websocket connection is working very well local instance, using nest js framework and generated the gateway to integrateb the websocket functionality for including chat feature in the app.
when executed locally the client is able to connect to the socket instance and emit the message and recieve message from the server
on Production app is running on nginx server and configured the app for the websocket were it location is socket.io
When user opens the app it connects to the server and the websocket assigned to it
The client app is unable to emit any message to the server and recieve from the server.
The app catches the new connection to websocket and it disconnection.
It is unable to listen to the event which are emitted from the client app.
`Nest JS CLI v7.5.1`
`Node version v 12.19.0`
`npm version v6.14.8`